# download all files and directories from a qt repo

Tags: download

I want to download all these examples from this repo- [Qt5.12](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/examples/quick?h=5.12). I tried with wget with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273743/using-wget-to-recursively-fetch-a-directory-with-arbitrary-files-in-it). just got an html file. is there any easy solution? its impossible to download and copy each file separately

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Git repository, so use `git clone` with the URL shown in the "Summary" tab:

```
git clone https://code.qt.io/qt/qtdeclarative.git
```